# Javascript Callbacks not waiting for end of previous command

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a series of Javascript commands I need to execute sequntially.
The process should be as follows

1. Find all Divs with class="##### Open"
2. Change height of all these to 0%
3. Remove className " Open" leaving class="#####"
4. Set height of div with given ID to 100% and change to class="#### Open"

Unfortunately the script is removeing the classname prior to changing the height and I'm baffled as to why

```
    clearClass(id, resetClass);


    if (typeof clearClass != 'function') {
        function clearClass(id, callBack) {
//Find all divs with class="#### Open"
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("Open");
            for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                if (divs.item(i).id != id) {
                    divs.item(i).style.height = "0%";
//make heights of these 0%
                }
            }
            return callBack(id, toggleClass);
        }
    }
    if (typeof resetClass != 'function') {
        function resetClass(id, callBack) {
//Find all divs with class="#### Open"
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("Open");
            for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                if (divs.item(i).id != id) {
//Remove "Open" class to leave class="####"
                    var DivClass2 = divs.item(i).className;
                    divs.item(i).className = DivClass2.replace("Open", "")
                }
            }
            return callBack(id);
        }
    }
    if (typeof toggleClass != 'function') {
        function toggleClass(id) {
//Change height of selected ID and give it class="#### Open"
            if (document.getElementById(id).style.height == "100%") {
                document.getElementById(id).style.height = "0%";
                var DivClass = document.getElementById(id).className;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    document.getElementById(id).className = DivClass.replace("Open", "")
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                document.getElementById(id).style.height = "100%";
                setTimeout(function () {
                    document.getElementById(id).className += " Open"

                }, 1000);

            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone shed any light on where I'm going wrong??

Added comments, though I think it's fairly straightforward anyway.
Can I respectfully ask that further responses are in relation to the question I have asked and not why I choose to do things the way I do.
BTW  I don't want to use Jquery, it needs to be written in native Javascript

Comment: Why do you need to use `if (typeof xxxx != 'function')`? If I create an example with your code I always get errors `Uncaught TypeError: clearClass is not a function(…)` because it's not yet defined. Do you define the same functions also somewhere else?

Comment: The script is contained in an aspx custom user control, therefore it may occur several times in a page depending how many times I place the control in my page.

Comment: I feel it's a unnecessary complex code. Too much DOM operation specially in loop.  Can you please clarify little and add some comments in code.

Comment: There is no need to use callback.

Comment: Care to elaborate on that gu?  If I don't use callbacks all 3 sequences fire together, rather than being sequential.